# Handle a JSON response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have this code below. I am using an AJAX call and then I need to read a json as a response. In my controller I have this:

```
def create
  # some code
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to 'index' }
    format.json { render :json => {:test =>"test"} }
  end
end
```

How do i read the json response? In which file should I put the javascript code??

```
$('...').live('ajax:success',function(data, status, xhr){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
});
```

I tried in the application.js file but it doesn't work

Comment: In your routes, do you have a call to Controller#create.

Comment: Additionally, you will want to direct your app to the Controller#create PATH (and) probably place your js in create.js.erb when making the js transaction. (and sorry for the vagueness/un-helpfulness, I started answering this while on the phone and trying to picture the code I wrote the other day in my head)

Comment: I find a way but i am not sure that is the right way, In order to read the {:test =>"test"} i had to add this to my AJAX link: Lhtml => {data-type="json"} and access it within a separate js file. One thing that is odd is the json data was available in the status variable instead of the data variable in the ajax:success callback in the code above